# Redirect https://subdomain.example.com to https://example.com/subdomain

Tags: apache

I'm trying to redirect traffic, and I've managed to make it work on `HTTP` with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wiki\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/wiki/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^db\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/db/$1 [L]
```

So far I haven't gotten it to work with `HTTPS`. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Where are you adding your rewrite rules? In the virtual host or `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to duplicate the code for `HTTPS` but set the `RewriteCond` to `%{HTTPS} =on` for the SSL redirect. I would also set the `RewriteBase` option as well as setting the `R=301` flag on the redirect. Further you can simplify things a bit by using a back reference to the `RewriteCond` by using `%N` for wiki/db -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# HTTP Redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(wiki|db)\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# HTTPS Redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(wiki|db)\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If your domain name might change in the future and you want to make sure you are redirecting based on the match, you can also use more back references in your `RewriteCond` -

```
# HTTPS Redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(wiki|db)\.(example\.com)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%2/%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for HTTPS. HTTP doesn work fine, but the HTTPS redirect doesn't work.

Could it have anything to do with the SSL cert being a wildcard self-cigned cert for the domain?

Comment: It's unlikely that it's related to the wildcard SSL cert - the `%{HTTPS} =on` check just looks at whether the connection is secure or not. Are you sure that the VirtualHost for both is set to the same location? Have you tried `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on` (without the `=` sign)?

Comment: I figured it out, and honestly, it's kinda embarrassing actually. I had 1 vhost file both containing my SSL and non-SSL site, pointing to the same directory. But I had set the wrong AllowOverride in the SSL site. Once I corrected that, the above code worked! - So thanks to doublesharp!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the redirection to happen for HTTP and HTTPS, just take out the rewrite condition that is stopping the rewrite from applying when the HTTPS environmental variable is set to on.

Comment: I'd like the rewrite to happen for both HTTP and HTTPS. Right now, with the above code, it only works for HTTP.

I've tried the obvious: Removing the RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on but that doesn't work. HTTPS still doesn't redirect.